# How to get datas from facebook Graph API response

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

Somehow I can't find solution for this. I have a request for Facebook user's albums:

```
new Request( session, "/me/albums", null, HttpMethod.GET, albumsRequest ).executeAsync();
```

and callback for that request:

```
    private Request.Callback albumsRequest =  new Request.Callback() {
        @Override 
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        }
    };
```

Now how can I get all returned datas from ***response*** object? A simple example should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returned response is JSON object in outter GraphApiObject.

Use this:

`JSONObject innerJson = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();`

`JSONArray data = innerJson.getJSONArray("data");`